# Ошибка при рендеринге (ReactDOM.render)

Tags: reactjs, dom

Только начинаю изучать REACT и уже столкнулся  с простой ошибкой! Дамы не терять время в пустую прошу подсказать в чем моя ошибка и ,если Вас не затруднит, поделиться списком литературы/статей которые помогут мне в изучении. Желательно последовательный список, т.к. я совсем новичек.
Вот сам код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="js/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-dom.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <div id="add"></div>

    <div id="result">
      <label for="" id="resultLine"></label>
    </div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
          <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required>,
        document.getElementById("add") 
        );
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ругается на input.

```
babel.min.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (3:10)
  1 | 
  2 |         ReactDOM.render(<p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
> 3 |           <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required>,
    |           ^
  4 |         document.getElementById("add") 
  5 |         );
  6 |     
    at t.J.raise (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.ge.jsxParseElementAt (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.ge.jsxParseElement (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.parseExprAtom (babel.min.js:8)
    at te.parseExprSubscripts (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeUnary (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseExprOps (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeConditional (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeAssign (babel.min.js:6)
    at t.parseMaybeAssign (babel.min.js:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `render` принимает один дом нод, а вы передаете два. Оберните их в `div`.

```
 ReactDOM.render(
     <div>          
         <p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
         <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required>
     </div>,
    document.getElementById("add") 
 );
```

Comment: Спасибо, но,к сожалению, не работает.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unterminated JSX contents (6:11)
  4 |          <p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
  5 |          <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required>
> 6 |      </div>,
    |            ^
  7 |     document.getElementById("add") 
  8 |  );
  9 |`

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK судя по ошибке нету открывающегося тега `<div>` вначале

Comment: с разметкой все в порядке! Все заработало когда я дописал разрывающий тэг `</input>` . Хотелось бы понять , по какой причине так происходит?

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
             <div>          
                 <p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
                 <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required> </input>
             </div>,
      document.getElementById("add") 
      );`
Вот так все работает!